# Send data over http asynchronously

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I am new in C# and I wold like to send web request asynchronously. I use HttpWebRequest with method `POST`. Problem is, If I use function `GetRequestStream()`, my application freezes even if I have getting response asynchronously. I read, function `GetRequestStream()` immediately tries to communicate with server. I found function `BeginGetResponse()`, but I don't understand how to use it.

Could somebody explain me how does it work? How to write post data asynchronously?

I would like to write function like (no matter how many other private functions I have to write):

```
public delegate void ReceiveFunc(HttpWebResponse response);

public static void sendRequest(string url, HttpWebRequest request, string content, ReceiveFunc callback) {
    // Return response back to callback
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look into the `HttpClient` class and the `async-await` keywords. It'll make it easier on you.

Comment: `GetRequestStream()` is not an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov is right: `HttpClient` is easier to use. But if you're new to C# I highly recommend to read into `async/await` first.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will look into that class, it seems good. If you write it as answer, I flag it as answer to this question.

Comment: Well, class `HttpClient` doesn't exist. What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using C# 5.0 you should be using the new `async-await` keywords with the Async functions.

Instead of `GetRequestStream()` you can use `Stream s = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()`

When you want to asynchronously receive the response you would then call:

```
HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()
```

This will make your life much easier than using the old method of callbacks with Begin and End functions.

Just keep in mind that wherever you use the `await` keyword the function must be marked `async`

Here's the MSDN article on using the async-await keywords:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx